# Secure ffmpeg streaming connection?

Tags: security, ffmpeg

I've googled & "stackoverflow-ed" but have not found any article about securing the ffmpeg streaming.

I want to stream my webcam/ desktop screen to the lan/internet but the first thing in my mind is that there's no way to secure the stream from eavesdropper, or someone that want to alter the stream?

Please someone tell me that I was wrong?

---

Update : I'm gona multicast the data using UDP protocol.

Comment: SSH is all you need for stuff like this.

Comment: Yes, but ffmpeg streaming use almost UDP intead of TCP. So I need to kinda pushing the UDP back & forth in a SSH tunnel ?

Comment: Thanks! VPN is a little overkill solution, do you think so? ffmpeg is opensource and I hope some guys integrated DTLS into it sooner or later.

Comment: What does it have to do with FFmpeg?  Nothing really.  FFmpeg uses existing protocols and standards, so those protocols and standards would have to support built-in security.  I'm not familiar with all of the streaming standards available, but none that I work with have any built-in mechanism for security.  VPN is likely overkill if all you need are these video streams, but if you have many of them and are considering other things such as control protocols, VPN might be the simplest way.

Comment: I've got the solution for this problem. For those who have the same stuff like me: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#tls

Comment: You should post that as an answer, and move your question over to SuperUser where it is more on-topic.

Comment: Yes, but it's now on-hold. I don't have sufficient permission to move it or even post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I've found the answer myself. So, if you want to securely stream your sensitive data over network, you could try using some ffmpeg built-in secure protocol, such as : TLS, SRTP, etc. All the detail could be found here :

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#tls